# How to loop over columns with multiple ranges in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop over columns to check if each cell in same row of my range `Union(Range("A2:A5"), Range("C2:E5"))` is not empty if it is highlight the empty cell  then check for the second row of my range. I am not sure how to approach this problem since my range is a union of multiple columns.  any  help with that ?

[image]

```
Union(Range("A2:A5"), Range("C2:E5")).Columns.Count
```

I am getting 1 as a result even if I use this `Union(Range("A2:A5"), Range("C2:E5")).end(xlToLeft).Columns` ( I think I should get 2 instead)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Union(Range("A2:A5"), Range("C2:E5"))
Dim currCell As Range
For Each currCell In r
    'do your testing here
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, I did this, but what if I have an empty row and I want to skip that, this  where I am not sure how to do. if there is at least one cell within a row is not empty highlight it otherwise skip if the row is empty

Comment: Post what you tried in the part of the code I showed above where it says "do your testing here"...